# nodemailer sendMail callback function never run

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, nodemailer

I have a nodejs code which send email using nodemailer module. Email is being sent successfully but the callback function never executes. So I am unable to notify the user whether the email is sent or not. Can anyone help on this?

```
var mailOptions = {
        from: emailFrom,
        to: emailTo,
        subject: subject,
        html: content,
        attachments: attachments,
}
transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {                        
            console.log("Error in sending mail");
        }                   
        console.log("Success");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `function` keyword instead of arrow function( `=>` ) as one of the reason might be the node or nodemailer version and inside error check always write `return` keyword otherwise it'll keep on executing the code.

```
transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
  if (error) {                        
    return console.log("Error in sending mail");
  }                   
  console.log("Success");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as Promise, working for me

```
mail
  .sendMail(mailOptions)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  });
```